# Rotate an array by k steps in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, for-loop, rotation

We have given an array of n size and we to have to rotate it by k times where k can be greater than n in some cases .

My try -

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void inputarray(int arr[],int size){
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        cin>>arr[i];
    }
}


int main(){
    
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int arr[100];

    inputarray(arr,n);

    int ansarr[n];

    int k;
    cin>>k;

    k = k%n;
    int j=0;

    for(int i =n-k;i<n;i++){
        ansarr[j++] = arr[i];
    }
    for(int i=0;i<=k;i++){
        ansarr[j++]=arr[i];
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cout<<ansarr[i];
    }

}
```

My output is coming correct for k>2 like my output for k=3 is -

> 6

> 1 2 3 4 5 6

> 3

> 456123

Which is correct but for k <2 like k = 2 , 1 and 0 my output is not coming correct . Like for K=2 my output is -

> 6

> 1 2 3 4 5 6

> 2

> 561234199699

So where am I doing wrong can anyone please tell .

Comment: you can use `std::rotate`

Comment: Why do you start your first `for` loop at `n-k`, and not `k+1`? The second one goes from 0 to `k`.

Comment: The first loop assigns to `k` elements in `ansarr`. The second loop also assigns to `k` elements in `ansarr`. This only works if `2*k == n`.

Comment: `int arr[100];` and `int ansarr[n];` - One uses a constant, the other is a VLA. Why?

Comment: @KarstenKoop nice catch thanks , but why its showing wrong answer in n-k and correct in k+1 bcz both mean the same ?

Comment: Why do you think `n-k` and `k+1` mean the same? If `n` is 6 and `k` is 0, `n-k` is 6 and `k+1` is 1.

Comment: A side note: why don't you use `std::vector` instead of c style arrays ? (plus c++ doesn't support VLAs).

Comment: Another side note: if this seemed to work for k > 3, it was only because undefined behaviour can appear to work sometimes.

Comment: If you can't use rotate, investigate what you can do with a modulo operator.

Comment: You are only copying part of the original array into the ansarr in the wrong order, which results in incorrect rotation for k < 2.

Answer (score 1):

You can perform the rotation with a single loop, and this is completely bulletproof, using

```
for (int i= 0; i < n; i++)
{
   ans[i]= arr[(i + k) % n];
}
```

Now you can eliminate the modulo inside the loop by noting that `i + k` remains in `[0, n)` for `i` in `[- k, n - k)`, thus in `[0, n - k)`, and `i + k - n` remains in `[0, n)` for `i` in `[n - k, 2n - k)`, thus in `[n - k, n)`. So you can rewrite with two successive loops

```
k= k % n;
int i;
for (i= 0; i < n - k; i++)
{
   ans[i]= arr[i + k];
}
for (    ; i < n    ; i++)
{
   ans[i]= arr[i + k - n];
}
```

---

Caution: due to the behavior of the operator `%`, the above code will fail for `k < 0`.

Answer (score 0):

For starters pay attention to that variable length arrays like this

```
int ansarr[n];
```

are not a standard C++ feature. You should declare the array similarly to the array `arr`

```
int ansarr[100];
```

Or instead of arrays you could use standard container `std::vector`.

In any case your code is wrong at least because this for loop

```
for(int i =n-k;i<n;i++){
    ansarr[j++] = arr[i];
}
```

should start from `i` equal to `k` instead of `i = n - k`

```
for(int i = k;i<n;i++){
    ansarr[j++] = arr[i];
}
```

and correspondingly the second for loop should look like

```
for(int i=0;i < k;i++){
    ansarr[j++]=arr[i];
}
```

That is the condition of the loop should look like `i < k`.

Your program works for `k` equal to `3` because the expression `n - k` when `n` is equal to `6` yields the same value `3`.

Bear in mind that there is standard algorithm `std::reverse_copy` declared in the header `<algorithm>` that you could use.

Here is a demonstration program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 6;
    for (size_t k = 0; k < N; k++)
    {
        int a[N] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
        int b[N];

        std::rotate_copy( a, a + k, a + N, b );

        std::cout << k << ":";

        for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            std::cout << ' ' << b[i];
        }

        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
0: 1 2 3 4 5 6
1: 2 3 4 5 6 1
2: 3 4 5 6 1 2
3: 4 5 6 1 2 3
4: 5 6 1 2 3 4
5: 6 1 2 3 4 5
```

As for your approach with for loop then it is enough to use only one for loop. For example

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 6;
    for (size_t k = 0; k < N; k++)
    {
        int a[N] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
        int b[N];

        for (size_t j = 0, i = k; j < N; i = ( i + 1 ) % N)
        {
            b[j++] = a[i];
        }

        std::cout << k << ":";

        for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            std::cout << ' ' << b[i];
        }

        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

The program output is the same as shown above

```
0: 1 2 3 4 5 6
1: 2 3 4 5 6 1
2: 3 4 5 6 1 2
3: 4 5 6 1 2 3
4: 5 6 1 2 3 4
5: 6 1 2 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how either the question description or the current answers are "rotate it by k times," where "it" is the give array. They all seem to create a new array.

To rotate an array by k, first take k modulo the array length, then perform three steps (for example, `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, k = 3`):

Reverse the part up to index k:

```
{3, 2, 1, 4, 5}
```

Reverse the part from index k to the end:

```
{3, 2, 1, 5, 4}
```

Reverse the whole array:

```
{4, 5, 1, 2, 3}
```